# Multiple define in for-of loop with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

It is possible to define multiple variables in a `for-of` loop like in the code below?

```
let arr = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
for (let x = 0, y of arr){
  console.log(x++, y);
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
let arr = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
let x = 0;
for (let y of arr){
  console.log(x++, y)
}
```

So i want to convert this code into the first one (or like that) and thus reduce number of code lines.

Comment: Initializers in `for-of` loops aren’t allowed, actually, so no.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to use `let x` scoped to the `for` loop? Use `for-in` (or a normal `for` loop) and use the index, or use a block (`{`…`}`) around the `for` loop and put `let x` in _that_ block. Or even better: `Array.prototype.forEach` or `Array.prototype.map` with a function using an `item` and `index` argument!

Comment: To reduce code lines U can use arrays [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function, it receives as params index and value. See [example](http://www.es6fiddle.net/iejy70o5/)

Comment: Actually, i use a bit more complex code: `for (let {attributes: {id,name}} of models){...}`, so i have wanted to add one more variable (`x`) in `for-of` loop. And `forEach` in this case will not help (to reduce code lines). Anyway, thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot declare-and-initialise variables normally (like you can in `for` loops) in `for … of` or `for … in` loops.

What you can do though is destructuring, and for your use case there's the [`.entries()` iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) that includes an index:

```
for (let [x, y] of ['red', 'green', 'blue'].entries())
    console.log(x, y);
```

Comment: can i change `y` to something like `{y: {y1, y2}}` and `['red', ...]` to object like `{y: {y1: 'foo', y2: 'bar'}}` here?

Comment: @mqklin: sure, you can nest destructuring expressions however you want. `for (let [x, {y: {y1, y2}}] of [{y: {y1: …, y2: …}}, …].entries())` would work just as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible, you can define only one variable in [for...loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Compilers such as [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) or [es6fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/) returns an error for such definition.